# Which python graphic library for moving dots

Tags: python, graphics, python-imaging-library

im currently working on a projects which involves an ai moving dots to a specific target using a genetic algorithm. 
I have dots, which move and then stop moving, and i have a boarder aswell as a target. My Question is which library to use when it comes to visualizing the dots.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This site is not for software recommendation, but I like matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can use the following code to get idea for your project

[Click here to download canvas image for input to following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN072.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\canvas2.jpg',1)

for i in range(10,260,20):
    time.sleep(0.5)     #To visualise dots one by one
    cv2.circle(img,(i, i),10, (0,0,255), -1) #draw circle
    cv2.imshow('frame',img)     #show output image
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
```

### It shows dots one by one like in following final image,

[image]

Comment: The basic concept of using OpenCV's `imshow()` is good, but I wonder why you have introduced a second, unnecessary dependency on PIL when you could perfectly easily use OpenCV drawing functions? Further, OpenCV uses BGR ordering while PIL uses RGB so your colours are going to go wrong unless you use `imshow('frame', pix[...,::-1])`

Comment: You have my vote anyway, because OpenCV `imshow()` is an easy way to visualise dynamic data ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Thanks for suggestion, I will definitely take a note of it, its something new to me as I had very basic knowledge about these packages.